# Reflection IL Code

Tags: .net, reflection.emit, dynamic-class

I'm new to reflections. I need to create a class which inherits from a parent class. I need to create a readonly property. This property calls an existing function in the parent class by passing an argument 25.

Everything works fine, except that I am unable to pass the value 25 to the function being called. Below is the code that generates the class. Please assist. Thanks.

```
    Public Shared Function GetDynamicClass() As Type
        Dim asmName As New AssemblyName
        asmName.Name = "MyAssm"

        Dim asmBuilder As AssemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly (asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)
        Dim mdlBuilder As ModuleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyDynModule")

        Dim TypeBldr As TypeBuilder = mdlBuilder.DefineType("MyDynClass", TypeAttributes.[Public] Or TypeAttributes.[Class])
        TypeBldr.SetParent(GetType(MyParent))

        Dim PropertyName As String = ""
        Dim PropBldr As PropertyBuilder = Nothing
        Dim GetSetAttr As MethodAttributes = Nothing
        Dim currGetPropMthdBldr As MethodBuilder = Nothing
        Dim currGetIL As ILGenerator = Nothing
        Dim mi As MethodInfo = Nothing

        PropertyName = "SurveyDate"
        PropBldr = TypeBldr.DefineProperty(PropertyName, PropertyAttributes.None, GetType(Object), New Type() {GetType(Object)})
        GetSetAttr = MethodAttributes.[Public] Or MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        currGetPropMthdBldr = TypeBldr.DefineMethod("get_value", GetSetAttr, GetType(Object), Type.EmptyTypes)
        currGetIL = currGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator()
        mi = GetType(MyParent).GetMethod("GetProgress")

        currGetIL.DeclareLocal(GetType(Object))
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0)
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8)
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mi)

        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
        PropBldr.SetGetMethod(currGetPropMthdBldr)

        Return TypeBldr.CreateType

    End Function
```

Comment: You can simply write in c# what you want code do then compile and open assembly with reflector and select IL disassembler.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you changed this:

```
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0)
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8)
```

into this:

```
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 25)
    currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8)
```

LDC_I4_0 is an opcode that loads the value "0". LDC_I4, on the other hand, lets you specify the actual argument yourself.

(Caveat: untested, got this from reading the docs)

Comment: Than you buddy. It worked with currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 25).
Thanks a million.